# File Index to text file in batch - Sort as creation date within for

Tags: date, batch-file

I'm writing a file directory to a text file with

```
(for %%i in (*.jpg *.jpeg) do @echo file '%cd%\%%i%newline%duration 10) >> index.txt
```

Is there a way to sort the textlines via creation date and time of the files within the directory inside the for?

Comment: Use the DIR command options to list the files with their create date and list them in the order you want.

Comment: `dir /?` or `help dir` from a command prompt.

Comment: I found the command but this will not sort it in that way to the textfile, i tried `dir /od
(for %%i in (*.jpg *.jpeg) do @echo file '%cd%\%%i%newline%duration 10) >> index.txt`

Comment: @Deex in what help file or even what website did it show you that you could use the DIR command like that with the FOR command?

Comment: I didn't find a file to this, but i'm trying otherwhise i wouldn't ask. Do you have a better idea?

Comment: @Deex, if you read the help file for the `DIR` command like we have suggested you would notice that it also has a `/T` option.  Your question says you want create date so you would use the `W` option with the /T option.  Assuming you want to do something with the output of the `DIR` command you will want to use a `FOR /F` command to capture the output of the `DIR` command. `FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('dir /b /od /tw *.jpg *.jpeg') DO ......`

Comment: Thank you, i was not even close to a solution. I tought maybe dir /od could be used as some kind of global if it is before the for. Thanks, learned something new.

Comment: @Deex, the `DIR` command syntax is pretty cut and dry in the help file. File path and file name with options. Period! I have programmed in a lot of scripting and programming languages in my 46 years on this planet and I can't say I have ever seen that syntax for using two commands together.

Comment: Personally, I'd prefer `FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('dir /b /od /tw *.jp*^|findstr /e /i /L "jpg jpeg"') DO...` as I've a notion that `dir` executes twice - once for each argument. This form finds all the files with an extent `.jp*` then filters the names for the explicit `/L` (literal) `/i` (case-irrelevant) `/e` ending `jpg` or  `jpeg`, so it will exclude `.jp2`s for instance.

Comment: @Magoo, I agree that it does look like the `DIR` command executes twice but piping has an inherent overhead so your code is actually slower when parsing 500 jpg and 500 jpeg files.  The difference is negligible though.  I ran each set of code ten times and it averages 0.2578 seconds to echo the result for my code and your code averaged 0.4239 seconds.